# Statistics Proof Question on Means

Tags: statistics

I believe I am missing something and could use some help identifying exactly what it is.

Consider $Q$ which is a function of random variable $U$. The mean of $Q(U)$ is then
$$
\langle Q(U) \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Q(V)f(V)dV
$$
Where $V$ is the sample space (all possible values of $U$) and $f(V)$ is the probability density function describing the random variable $U$.

Now consider two random variables $Q$ and $R$. I am asked to verify that $\langle \langle Q \rangle \langle R \rangle \rangle = \langle Q \rangle \langle R \rangle $. I get as far as the following:

$$
\langle \langle Q \rangle \langle R \rangle \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \langle Q \rangle \langle R \rangle  \right) f(V) dV\\
\langle \langle Q \rangle \langle R \rangle \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Q(V)f(V)dV \right) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} R(V)f(V)dV \right)  f(V) dV
$$
What is apparent to me is that if I am allowed to separate the integrals then I'll get the answer.
$$
\langle \langle Q \rangle \langle R \rangle \rangle = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(V)dV\right) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Q(V)f(V)dV \right) \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} R(V)f(V)dV \right)\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(V)dV = 1\\
$$
What I don't understand is *why* I can separate the integrals like this. If the integrand is a function of what is being integrated, I didn't think you could pull it out of the integral.

Comment: Notation question.    What is ⟨⟨Q⟩⟨R⟩⟩?  It looks like the mean of a product of means.  Since means are constant, you have nothing to prove!

Comment: Yes, it is mean of the product of the means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is completely unnecessary.  The mean is simply a number, so the product of two means is also a number.  So its mean is its value.  Therefore the mean of a product of means is the product of means.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something - I am wondering how I can move one integral out of another if they are all a function of V.

Comment: ⟨⟨Q⟩⟨R⟩⟩=∫(⟨Q⟩⟨R⟩)f(V)dV requires a density function f(V).  However there is no such thing, since ⟨Q⟩⟨R⟩ is a constant.

Comment: The easiest explanation is using an elementary calculus idea.  $\int cf(x)dx=c\int f(x)dx,$ where $c$  is a constant.  For your expression, c=$(Q⟩⟨R⟩$ while $\int f(V)dV=1$.